# Verifying the search results populated in a table

Tags: testing, selenium, xpath, robotframework

There is a tab to search among the displayed list of vehicles and their details in the webpage. Here for example I am searching for the phone numbers which are all containing 407, It will return the phone numbers which are all contains 407.  I am able to do this through robot-framework. But the challenge here is that I should verify the returned results. Those results are populated in a table.

Table code looks like this

```
<tr class="x-grid-row">
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-LandmarkEditIcon   x-action-col-cell x-grid-cell-first">
        <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
        <img alt="" src="/assets/ui/images/menu/edit-menu-item.png" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0   small-icon-image" data-qtip="Edit STEIN BEER GARDEN new">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1225   " data-qtip=" Double click to view the vehicles present. ">
        <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">STEIN BEER GARDEN new</div>
    </td>
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1226   ">
        <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">test reg 145</div>
    </td>
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1227   ">
        <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">0</div>
    </td>
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1228   ">
        <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">895 Villa Street, Mountain View, CA, 94041</div>
    </td>
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1229   ">
        <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">circle</div>
    </td>
    <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1230    x-grid-cell-last">
        <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">Phone Number</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I just pasted a row here. Table structure looks like the above row. I need to verify the phone numbers whether it is matching the search criteria or not. Im new to robot framework. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Note : Id's are dynamic

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Table Should Contain](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Table%20Should%20Contain) keyword from the [robotframework-selenium2 library](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library) and give the right locator to identify the table you are looking in. But notice that it will look for your expected phone numbers in the whole table. If you want to check something more accurate (given cell, given column, given row...) then check the [other keywords available in the library](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html).

```
*** Settings ***
Library     robotframework-selenium2

*** Test Cases ***
check phone numbers in table
    table should contain    mytable    407-832-232
    table cell should contain    mytable    row=3    column=6    407-832-232
```

Comment: Does it check for all the rows ? For example if the search has returned  more than 100 rows means how could I verify it ? and moreover Since there are div's inside every cell these aren't working. I tried it before